# ServiceWorker Cache on Install

Tags: html, service-worker

I'm trying to figure out how I can cache a dynamic page on install? My current page is `/product/1/view`

```
self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
event.waitUntil(
        caches.open('kiosk-assets').then(function (cache) {
            return cache.addAll([
                '/' // This is the problem it caches the origin path i need the current page cached. See register below
                '/css/product.min.css'
            ])
        }),
....
```

Here is how I register my worker. This is registered on `/product/1/view`

```
window.navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js', {scope: `/product/${id}/view`})
```

I can change how I register if this could be a possibility.

Comment: Where are you registering the sw from? and, did the registration succeed with what you have posted above?

can you log the scope and see that it is scoped as you want it to?

Comment: At The install event,  the sw has no idea what it might control, Nor after registration and activation even, does it control the DOM to fetch the current url. you might have to have a message thread between the registrar and the worker and cache on message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think, you can do that `onInstall`

At least not with the service worker by itself. For the simple reason that, while the service worker is being installed, it has No idea what clients it is controlling / will control.

Also, Even an active serviceworker has No control over the DOM.
Hence, It has no way of knowing what the current url is.

you can either cache the url on `activate` , and or a `fetch` event

or,

you need the client to ping the worker, while it is installing it.

If caching the registering page strictly `onInstall` is all you need, then ,

Send a Message via `postMessage` from the page that registers the worker

```
if ( 'serviceWorker' in navigator ) {
navigator.serviceWorker.register( 'sw.js' )
    .then( function ( success ) {
        console.log( 'scope', success.scope );
        if ( success.installing ) {
            let sw = success.installing;
            sw.addEventListener( 'statechange', function ( event ) {
                if ( event.target.state == 'installed' ) {
                    let loc = window.location.toString();
                    let message = {
                        action: 'cache',
                        location: loc
                    }
                    sw.postMessage( message );
                }
            } )
        }
    } );
}
```

And use the `message` event within the worker, to cache the url

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use `sw-precache` library for static and dynamic caching of data.

Integrate it with you build environment (Gulp, Grunt, Webpack). Sw-precache serves all your static files and update it accordingly. sw-precache has the options of `runtime-caching` which fill fulfill your needs

You can learn about the library here - https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache